# Extract values of attribute from a line in file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

I have a file with a big single line (only one line) containing multiple attributes. File is XML-like but is not valid XML, so not sure if XML utilities can be used. The line is like below:

```
<a="1" b="2" time="10" c="3" time="1" time="3" d="1" e="1" f="1" time="10" .... />
```

I want to extract all the values of time and sum it up. `time` can be any where in the line. GNU grep is not available so cannot use `grep -oP`

Can someone help me with bash script/command?

Comment: Do you have `xsltproc` available? If so, you could do this by properly parsing the content as XML, as opposed to trying to interpreted it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Perl to extract the numbers in `time="..."` and sum them up:

```
perl -pne 'use List::Util qw(reduce); $_ = reduce { $a + $b } /time="(\d+)"/g' < file
```

The trick is that the `/.../` operator in Perl returns a list of the values in the capture groups.
In this example the values in `time="..."`.

The `List::Util::reduce` is to calculate their sum.

The `-ne` is to read the content of `stdin` into the `$_` variable,
and the `-p` is to automatically print the value of the `$_` variable (which we replaced with the sum of values).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need GNU grep's `-P` here:

```
grep -o 'time="[^"]*"' infile | cut -d '"' -f2 | paste -s -d+ | bc
```

This extracts all the `time="dd"` strings:

```
time="10"
time="1"
time="3"
time="10"
```

`cut` with `"` as the delimiter then extracts the second field, which is the number:

```
10
1
3
10
```

`paste -s -d+` puts everything back on a single line, using `+` as the delimiter:

```
10+1+3+10
```

and `bc` calculates the result:

```
21
```

---

If your grep does not even have the `-o` option, which I just realize is neither in POSIX nor AIX grep, you could do something like

```
tr ' ' '\n' < infile | grep 'time=' | cut -d '"' -f2 | paste -s -d+ | bc
```

To get each key/value pair on a separate line first. This should work on any system with POSIX conforming versions of these utilities.

Comment: I like the pipeline, though I've never been a fan of `bc` for integer math.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could also do `echo $((<pipeline>))` without bc, but what don't you like about bc for integer math?

Comment: Only dislike for integer math is `$((...))` is already part of POSIX. `bc` or `calc` (I really like `calc`) is fine for floating point. You can use it for integer, but it just takes an additional pipe and call to `bc` (which gets costly if you are performing the calculation within a loop). At least that is my thought process (it may be way down in the weeds or a bit bipolar...)

Answer (score 0):

How about `awk`?

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "; FS="\""; sum=0} /time*/{sum+=$2} END {print sum}' data.xml
```

Explanation:

- `RS` stands for *record separator*, so we ask `awk` to process one *key=value* pair at a time.
- `FS` stands for *field separator*, so we split the record by `"`, which makes it easy to extract the numerical value.
- `/time*/{sum+=$2}` will match any record starting with *time* and will add the value to our global `sum`.
- At the end of the program we just print the value we accumulated in `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting summation. You can also do it with `grep -ow` and bash alone. Note: to make it POSIX shell compliant, you need to pipe the output of the `grep` expression to `read` rather than using *process substitution*. (and use `sum="${sum}+$n"` instead of the `+=` variant) You can do the following:

```
$ c=0; sum=; \
while read -r n; do \
    ((c > 0)) && sum+="+$n" || sum="$n"; ((c++)); \
done < <(grep -ow "[0-9]*" yourfile); \
echo $((sum)))
33
```

Add it to the mix. If you understand all the answers, you will have quite a few more tools to add to your shell toolbox.

**Input File**

```
$ cat yourfile
a="1" b="2" time="10" c="3" time="1" time="3" d="1" e="1" f="1" time="10"
```